# Check if pandas dtype is string[python?

Tags: python, pandas, types, user-defined-types

I want to check if the dtype of my columns are of the following type: string[python].

```
print(data.dtypes)

1     string
2     string
3     string
4     string
5     string
6     int
7     string
8     string
9     float
10    string
dtype: object
```

I want to perform something like:

```
data.dtypes == string[python]
```

and in returns:

```
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     False
7     True
8     True
9     False
10    True
dtype: object
```

ps

```
print(data.dtypes[0])
string[python]
```

Comment: Well, from your output, it would seem they are.

Comment: I think you need to phrase your problem more clearly, with an example of where you are unsure about the dtype.

Comment: I assume the "[python" and "[python]" parts are attempts at tags/clarification of the language, not an actual part of the type? Because "string[python]" is not a type that exists.

Comment: Why "string[python]" though? That doesn't make sense: you're working with Pandas, which is the Python eco-system, so any "string" is already Python. What other string types are you using?

Comment: Compare to 'object': `df.dtypes == 'object'`, unless you're using the [newer 'string' type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html), in which case `df.dtypes == 'string'` works.

Comment: I have never seen `print(data.dtypes[0])` produce `string[python]` as output. If that is your output, please provide a complete example *with the input* that produces that.